# Loop-in on GroupBy - Aggregation in Cascading

Tags: cascading

When aggregation on GroupBy is applied on any Pipe, resultant fields have grouping key & aggregated value.
I want all fields in addition to aggregated value in **Cascading**

Example :
    input :

```
       A|a1|b1|12
       B|b2|c2|10
       A|a3|a3|5
```

Normal Aggregated Output :

```
A|17
B|10
```

**I want** : output same as input but in addition aggregated column as well--

```
A|a1|b1|12|17
B|b2|c2|10
A|a3|a3|5|17
```

So , How to loop on result of GroupBY to aggregate & print all rows in Cascading?

```
    Pipe group = new GroupBy(someTuplePipe, groupKey, true);
    group  = new Every(g1, Fields.ALL, new Count(new Fields("sum")), Fields.ALL);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found was to create a custom `Buffer` and use a List to save the incoming `TupleEntry` calculate the sum and write out the sum by iterating through the previous saved List

```
@Override
public void operate(FlowProcess flowProcess, BufferCall bufferCall) {
    Iterator<TupleEntry> iterator = bufferCall.getArgumentsIterator();
    List<TupleEntry> tupleEntryMap = new ArrayList<TupleEntry>();

    int sum = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        TupleEntry inputEntry = new TupleEntry(iterator.next());
        sum += inputEntry.getInteger("amount_field");
        tupleEntryMap.add(inputEntry);
    }

    for (TupleEntry result : tupleEntryMap) {
        result.setInteger("amount_field", sum);
        bufferCall.getOutputCollector().add(result);
    }
}
```

And Use it as you mentioned above.

```
Pipe group = new GroupBy(someTuplePipe, groupKey, true);
group  = new Every(group, new CustomBuffer(), Fields.REPLACE);
```

Comment: That Isn't it same as , grouping and then joining grouped stream with input stream ?

Comment: @ganeshtripathi Could you please elaborate. I'm having a hard time understanding you.

Comment: @ganeshtripathi Finally understood what you were trying to say :D . Yes the output would be the same as you mentioned, but it would add at-least 2 extra step to the flow.

Comment: I was talking more on memory and processing front.

Comment: These both will take same processing, That what I was upto .

Comment: Actually considering you will be working on lots of data, extra step in flow would  be inefficient. Look at it this way, to join these map-reduce has to be completed in the precious flow, which automatically increases processing. And in terms of memory, its an insignificant increase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105251/discussion-between-ganeshtripathi-and-riteshakya037).